# Android ImageView SRC via Data Binding

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I define a custom binding data adapter like below :

```
object DataBindingAdapters {

    @BindingAdapter("bind:imgRes")
    @JvmStatic
    fun setImageResource(imageView: ImageView, resource: Int) {
        imageView.setImageResource(resource)
    }

    @BindingAdapter("bind:visible")
    @JvmStatic
    fun View.setVisible(show: Boolean) {
        visibility = if (show) VISIBLE else GONE
    }
}
```

And with that I want to set the imageview using custom atribute like :

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:imgRes="@{item.iconResId}" />
```

But I get all the time the error below :

```
AAPT: error: attribute imgRes (aka com.*:imgRes) not found.
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing you can remove couple of line of code which is not really useful.

Replace this method :

```
 @BindingAdapter("imgRes")
  @JvmStatic
  fun setImageResource(imageView: ImageView, resource: Int) {
    imageView.setImageResource(resource)
}
```

with this  :

```
  @BindingAdapter("imgRes")
  fun setImageResource(imageView: ImageView, resource: Int) {
    imageView.setImageResource(resource)
}
```

Also remove object DataBindingAdapters { } because you really don't need this because you are not going to call this method.

So your file will look like :

DataBindingAdapters.kt

```
  @BindingAdapter("imgRes")
  fun setImageResource(imageView: ImageView, resource: Int) {
    imageView.setImageResource(resource)
 }

 @BindingAdapter("visible")
fun View.setVisible(show: Boolean) {
    visibility = if (show) VISIBLE else GONE
}  // you can do this stuff even in adapter you don't need @BindingAdapter("visible")
```

For View Visibility you don't need to use bind adapter you can do that in your model class.

```
 android:visibility="@{challenge.quizStatus.equals(Const.COMPLETED)?View.GONE : 
 View.VISIBLE,default=gone}"
```

Comment: Let me know if still stuck in any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should :

```
object DataBindingAdapters {

    @BindingAdapter("imgRes")
    @JvmStatic
    fun setImageResource(imageView: ImageView, resource: Int) {
        imageView.setImageResource(resource)
    }

    @BindingAdapter("visible")
    @JvmStatic
    fun View.setVisible(show: Boolean) {
        visibility = if (show) VISIBLE else GONE
    }
}
```

And:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    imgRes="@{item.iconResId}" />
```

Comment: Visibility can be set if you import View in xml. No need for binding adapters